# Magento2 - Price Layered Navigation Issue

Tags: magento2, price, layered-navigation, filter

When a product price is more than 100,000 . The price filter showing only two options

```
13,000 - 100,000
100,000 - 130,000
```

As filterable options , When i disabled the product which is having price more than 100,000. It is displaying following filter options.

```
10,000 - 20,000
20,000 - 30,000
30,000 - 40,000
40,000 - 50,000
50,000 - 60,000
60,000 - 70,000
70,000 - 80,000
80,000 - 90,000
```

Why the layered navigation displaying like this? Why it is not displaying other product price filter options if the product price is more than 100,000. Any settings needs to be changed?

Comment: You use any extensions for layered navigation??

Comment: I tried SY layered navigation. It is also showing same . https://github.com/SlavaYurthev/MultipleLayeredNavigation-M2